# Terrain based military upgrades - your terrain or the enemies'?

Tags: civilization-5

When you upgrade a military unit, e.g. an archer, and you have terrain based bonuses such as "15% attack bonus on rough terrain". If you choose such upgrade, when do you get the bonus, when the enemy is on rough terrain, or when you are on rough terrain?
Thanks.

Comment: I can imagine foot soldiers/swordsmen being 'your' terrain- the idea being that your guys are more nimble. Are there any similar speed boosts? If an archer gains a speed boost from rough terrain, its probably more likely that they get an attack bonus whilst standing on rough terrain themselves. I haven't played the game so I don't know for sure

Comment: I don't recall such boosts

Comment: Fair enough. Again I haven't played the game, I'm only drawing conclusions based on how I would program it if I developed it

Answer (score -1):

Whichever type of terrain the unit being attacked is standing on, is the terrain taken into account for any combat bonus.

Comment: The comments on the answer of the question I duplicated states otherwise!

Comment: @User52549 So they do.